# Error in React Application While applying MUI Date Picker

Tags: reactjs, date, material-ui, datepicker, date-range

I was trying to use mui date pickers in my application and to use it I installed three libraries

```
npm install @mui/x-date-pickers@next (version ^6.0.0-beta.4)
npm i dayjs (version ^1.11.7)
npm i @date-io/dayjs (version ^^2.16.0)
```

This is the code that I am trying to run in my website

```
import { AdapterDayjs } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs';
import { LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider';
import { DatePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker';
    
     <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
         <DatePicker />
     </LocalizationProvider>
```

Runtime errors are coming while doing npm start like

```
ERROR in./ node_modules/@mui/x-date-pickers/internals/hooks/useMobilePicker/useMobilePicker.js 64:21-33
```